# Загрузить видео в igtv через puppeteer

Tags: instagram, chromium, puppeteer

Гружу вручную через интерфейс - всё в порядке.
а кодом:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('#react-root > section > main > div > form > div > div._6CXdY.Ygphp.nFdnY > label > input');
await elementHandle.uploadFile("E:\test.mp4");
```

выдаёт ошибку мол повреждено или не поддерживаются кодеки.

До этого была точно такая же ошибка и при загрузки через интерфейс тоже.
После того как я скачал в папку с браузером сборку, которая поддерживает h.264 эта ошибка осталась только при загрузки видео кодом.

Что я недозаменил? в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в слеше!

```
await elementHandle.uploadFile("E:\test.mp4");
```

он должен быть обратным

```
await elementHandle.uploadFile("E:/test.mp4");
```